# How to check whether string is in an Arraylist<string> or not?

Tags: android

```
Boolean ans = nselectedfromadapter.contains("selected");
Log.d("ipdichodu", String.valueOf(nselectedfromadapter));

if (ans){
   /* Intent intent = new Intent(Viewhirings.this, Informaall.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list",nselectedfromadapter);
    intent.putExtra("jobname",jobname);

    startActivity(intent);*/
    Log.d("have or not", String.valueOf("have"));


}
    else {



    Log.d("have or not", String.valueOf("not"));
    }
```

I am having value selected in that nselectedfromadapter(Arraylist) but when i run beclow program it is Logging me "Not" . i dont what is the problem going on

Comment: check which data your `nselectedfromadapter` contains.

Comment: Check that nselectedfromadapter is well of type `ArrayList<**String**>`

Comment: check the "selected" text in arraylist and keep in mind the case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct! Just make sure of the following:

1)nselectedfromadapter is of type String.

2)The String "selected" is inserted with the correct spelling and letter casing.

3)Try using nselectedfromadapter.containsIgnoreCase("selected");

If you still have the problem, try using debugger mode to trace your code step by step.